# IE submit the forms twice

Tags: jquery, html, double-submit-problem

I have this problem in IE, sometimes my form is submitting twice. I know the issue of clicking the button twice and that is not the problem. But on my case I only click it once. I checked my records in the database and there are two records.

```
<input type="button" value="Approve" name="btn_approve" id="btn_approve">
<input type="button" value="Reject"  name="btn_reject" id="btn_reject">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_approve").click(function () {
        // some validation before submitting the form

        $("#my_form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Prevent the default behaviour of the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Approve" name="btn_approve" id="btn_approve">
<input type="button" value="Reject"  name="btn_reject" id="btn_reject">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_approve").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // some validation before submitting the form

        $("#my_form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct one. e.preventDefault(); should be executed first before submit(). Thanks!

Comment: I also had this just now with a self-created css button (a couple of div's put together). I don't know why, but this solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `#btn_approve` is actually a submit button *inside* of `#my_form`, you are triggering the form submission via `.submit` and the browser is also submitting it normally. Change to:

```
$("#btn_approve").on('click', function (e) {
   $("#my_form").trigger('submit');

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: On the code shown on the question, `btn_approve` is of type `button`.

Comment: @MartínCanaval 1. How do you know that 2. Why does it matter?

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Approve" name="btn_approve" id="btn_approve">` this is the first line on the code he posted. I'm just mentioning it just in case.

Comment: @MartínCanaval oh I see I thought you meant it was a button *element*.  I think the problem is that `type="button"` submits forms in IE but not the other browsers.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I time-stamp my records as I save them to the database. 
So if a record is submitted for a specific unique user, within 2 seconds from each other, I just ignore the duplicates.
This way I don't need to check for browser types and compatibility on the client side, just handle the issue on the server side, respectively of the browser.

```
        '' Count the number of submissions, for the user, within the 2 seconds.
        objRS.open "select count(*) as C FROM [ADS].[dbo].[VIP_USERS] where userid = '" & Trim(Request("USERID")) & "' and datediff(ss, created, GETDATE()) <= 2", Application("sConn")
```